# multiple but separate WHERE conditions in SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get user messages from the database where the user is either the sender or the recipient with one other unique user, and I can't figure out how to write the WHERE statement. This is what I have now:

```
$sql = " SELECT sender, 
       receiver, 
       timestamp, 
       message 
FROM   messages 
WHERE  ( receiver = '$log_username' 
         AND sender = '$messageOther' ) 
        OR ( receiver = '$messageOther' 
             AND sender = '$log_username' ) 
ORDER  BY timestamp DESC";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $message = $row["message"];
    $sender = $row["sender"];
    $receiver = $row["receiver"];
    $timestamp = $row["timestamp"];
    $messagehtml .= 'Sender: '.$sender.' | Receiver: '.$receiver.' | Message: '.$message.' | Timestamp '.$timestamp.'<br />';
    }
```

What's the best way of writing this to get that result?

Comment: That looks like it should work, what's the problem?

Comment: So what's wrong with that?

Comment: It's not giving me any output...

Comment: You are not generating any output. You aren't checking for any return values either to see if the query was successful in the first place.

Comment: Do you ever `echo $messagehtml`?

Comment: Yes, I echo it later in the document. I guess I haven't learned about checking for return values, I'm new to programing.

Comment: http://php.net/mysqli_query : See the second example. Look for return values of the functions to see if any errors were generated

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that `$log_username` should be either `sender` or `receiver` and the other value `$messageOther` should be either `sender` or `receiver` following query will work for you:

```
SELECT sender, receiver, timestamp, message 
FROM messages 
WHERE ((receiver='$log_username' AND sender='$messageOther') OR
(receiver='$messageOther' AND sender='$log_username'))
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

[<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5838c1/4)

<strike>Well instead of `AND` you need to use `OR` everywhere. Try following, it works on my test table:</strike>

```
SELECT sender, receiver, timestamp, message 
FROM messages 
WHERE ((receiver='$log_username' AND receiver='$messageOther') OR
(sender='$messageOther' AND sender='$log_username'))
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: That changes the logic completely imo

Comment: `receiver='$log_username' AND receiver='$messageOther'`  You mean to say that `$log_username` and `$messageOther` have to be *same* for this to work?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yes you are right. the first query was looking if any one variable matches with sender or receiver. I think user want that both the values should match with sender or receiver with any permutation.